# Google: "EcmaScript 5 getters and setters for properties are discouraged" Why?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

According to the [Google JS style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml) getters and setters are discouraged. Why is this?

[Mozilla JS Object docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) explicitly advocate using getters and setters in js. I'm confused about the discrepancy.

Comment: The first link is a style guide, making it subjective. The second link does not "advocate" using them, it only explains how to use them (which is what documentation does). Unfortunately, the question is too opinion-based to give a good answer for.

Comment: It's a _style guide_. It's how they choose to write code.

Comment: Where in that MDN page does it advocate using getters and setters?

Answer (score 1):

Because using getters and setters can, from the outside point of view be confusing.

Lets say I make an object `myObject` with the following property `status`. That property uses a getter and computes a result for getting it. Example:

```
const status = myObject.status;
const open = status.open; // true
const color = status.color; // "blue"
```

Now everytime I use `myObject.status` **it looks like I just access a direct property** but it s not true. In fact it **calls a function that can take a lot of computation**.

Now another person who didn't implement myObject comes in and  does this

```
const open = myObject.status.open; // true
const color = myObject.status.color; // "blue"
```

And it works ! **But** a potentially compute heavy function is called twice instead of once.
It can also have side effects (worst situation, don't use getters with sideeffects), and when you look for a bug and you don t know where it comes from it is hard to tell.

That is why some recommend to use `const status = myObject.getStatus();`. It is an **explicit** function call.